# how to add new sublist to Grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-variable

I am new to Grafana.  I have a dashboards like below and I want to add one more list call appmetrics under the kafka metrics.  I do not know how to add it. Thank you for the help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be4qF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a `Row` panel, which you need to add:

[image: Grafana add Row panel]

BTW: `Row` panel is [not recommended from Grafana v5](https://community.grafana.com/t/no-new-row-button/7649/3).